# Why can't I access my Drupal6 admin or pages?

Tags: drupal, admin, access-denied

I am reactivating an old Drupal project that was created by a past employee.  He left no instructions on how to access Drupal.  I gained access to the postgres database Drupal is using and changed everyone's password.  I also made sure all users had administrator role and that administrator role has all permissions.  When I log in with any of the users, I simply get "Access denied" for every page I try to go to.  I've tried /admin, /user, /node, and several other pages.  Changing the password definitely reset their password because I'm not getting an invalid login message, just an access denied message.  The site is first being authenticated through apache using LDAP, and I made sure there are apache users that match the Drupal users.  I am totally stumped.  As I said, the person who did this project initially is gone and can't be reached.  I have looked at several similar topic threads and can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

have you enabled the ldap mod in apache?
try /?q=user

is phpMyAdmin installed? Check users there as well.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but phpMyAdmin is for MySQL. My Drupal install seems to be using a postgres database(in fact I'm sure it is, because I accessed it and changed all the user credentials).

/?q=user doesn't help either; just another access denied message

Comment: yes, it's just that all the data for Drupal in the database can be accessed, but I missed the postgres. However, what about the ldap mod in Apache? That has to be enabled in the Apache config. If it is not, the ldap authentication will not work. I had the same problem recently until learning that. Can you get a command-line? you can login and then use this: $ sudo apt-get install php5-ldap

Comment: Ldap is installed and enabled.  I can clear the apache authentication.  It's just that any Drupal page I try to go to serves a Drupal "Access Denied" page.  It isn't throwing the usual html access denied page.  Perhaps I wasn't clear about that.